# How would I split a string after the spaces in haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, recursion

I know Haskell doesn't have loops, so I can't do that. I also know that recursion is "helpful" here, but that's about all I'm aware of. 
So far, I've gotten a basic type signature, which is

```
toSplit :: String -> [String]
```

Basically, it changes from a string into a list of words...

Thanks!

P.S. I want to use the `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` functions... not a library...

Comment: Use [**`words`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words).

Comment: [Entering that type signature into hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String+-%3E+%5BString%5D) gives you two options: `lines` or `words`.

Comment: _"...Haskell doesn't have loops..."_ Yes, because recursion replaces loops. This is why recursion is helpful here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to implement that yourself, first thing you need to do is find the first word.
You can do that with:

```
takeWhile (/=' ') s
```

If the string starts with delimiter characters you need to trim those first. We can do that with `dropWhile`.

```
takeWhile (/=' ') $ dropWhile (==' ') s
```

Now we have the first word, but we also need the rest of the string starting after the first word, on which we will recurse. We can use `splitAt`:

```
(_, rest) = splitAt (length word) s
```

And then we recurse with the `rest` of the string and cons the first word onto the result of that recursion giving us a list of all words.

And we need to define the base case, the result for the empty string which will terminate the recursion once there are no more characters.

```
toSplit :: String -> [String]
toSplit "" = []
toSplit s =
  let word = takeWhile (/=' ') $ dropWhile (==' ') s
      (_, rest) = splitAt (length word) s
  in word : toSplit (dropWhile (==' ') rest)
```

**Edit:** There is a bug in the code above and it's not handling an edge case properly.

The bug is that it's calling splitAt on the original `s` but this gives a wrong result if `s` has leading spaces:

```
*Main> toSplit " foo"
["foo","o"]
```

This should fix the bug:

```
let trimmed = dropWhile (==' ') s
    word = takeWhile (/=' ') trimmed
    (_, rest) = splitAt (length word) trimmed
```

That leaves one edge case:

```
*Main> toSplit " "
[""]
```

One possible solution is to use a helper function:

```
toSplit :: String -> [String]
toSplit = splitWords . dropWhile (==' ') 
    where
        splitWords "" = []
        splitWords s = 
          let word = takeWhile (/=' ') s
              (_, rest) = splitAt (length word) s
          in word : splitWords (dropWhile (==' ') rest)
```

Comment: You can use `span` instead of `takeWhile` and `splitAt`

Comment: Wow! Thanks!. @4castle In the question, I was asking about using `takeWhile`, but I definitely think that `span` would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

> I know Haskell doesn't have loops, so I can't do that. I also know
>   that recursion is "helpful" here...

**Yes**, Haskell use recursion rather then `for`, `while` loop structure that in imperative language.

In stead of write recursive function by myself, it is more common use `map`, `foldr (foldl)`, `unfoldr` or etc recursively traverse the list. The advantage of these functions is that you can concentrate what want to do in `step` function. Like your question, is suitable use `unfoldr` to accomplish it.

Here is an example with `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`:

```
import Data.Char (isSpace)
import Data.List (unfoldr)

toSplit::String->[String]
toSplit = unfoldr step 
    where step [] = Nothing
          step xs = Just (takeWhile (not . isSpace) xs, 
                          (dropWhile isSpace . dropWhile (not . isSpace)) xs)
```

But a little bit verbose, use `break` function may be more readable like:

```
toSplit' = unfoldr step
    where step [] = Nothing
          step xs = let (word, rest) = break isSpace xs
                    in  Just (word, dropWhile isSpace rest)
```